# Stored procedure error: Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My stored procedure is working fine, when I pass new input values on table `tbl_CreateFreeBet`, when I pass values which are already present it throws an error

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1. 1 row(s) effected

Getting the above error message, when I try to set value to my output as

```
SET @strResp = 'Free bet already exists'
```

It is returning "1 rows effected", but in this case there won't be any insert statements that would be executed.

PFB my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_CreateNewFreeBet
    (@matchId int,
     @tournamentId int,
     @freeBetAmount int,
     @freeBetMsg varchar(500),
     @userEmail nvarchar(256),
     @strResp varchar(256) output)
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    SET NoCount ON

    DECLARE @TransactionNewFreeBet varchar(20) = 'TranNewfreeBet'
    DECLARE @FreeBetCount int
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN @TransactionNewFreeBet
    SELECT 
        @FreeBetCount = COUNT(FreeBetID) 
    FROM
        tbl_CreateFreeBet 
    WHERE
        MatchID = @matchId AND TournamentID = @tournamentId

    IF @FreeBetCount < 50
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FreeBetID FROM tbl_CreateFreeBet 
                       WHERE FreeBetDescription = @freeBetMsg 
                         AND TournamentID = @tournamentId 
                         AND MatchID = @matchId)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_CreateFreeBet 
            VALUES (@freeBetMsg, @freeBetAmount, @tournamentId, @matchId)

            DECLARE @FreeBetId int

            SELECT @FreeBetId = FreeBetID 
            FROM tbl_CreateFreeBet 
            WHERE FreeBetDescription = @freeBetMsg 
              AND TournamentID = @tournamentId 
              AND MatchID = @matchId

            DECLARE @UserId nvarchar(128)

            SELECT @UserId = Id 
            FROM AspNetUsers 
            WHERE Email = @userEmail

            INSERT INTO tbl_UserFreeBets (FreeBetID, TournamentID, MatchID, UserForYes, UserForNo, UserForNoBets) 
            VALUES (@FreeBetId, @tournamentId, @matchId, @UserId, null, null)

            COMMIT TRAN @TransactionNewFreeBet

            SET @strResp = 'success'

            SELECT DISTINCT(tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetID), 
                tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetDescription, 
                tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetAmount, 
                tbl_CreateFreeBet.TournamentID, 
                tbl_CreateFreeBet.MatchID, 
                tbl_UserFreeBets.UserForYes, 
                tbl_UserFreeBets.UserForNo, 
                tbl_UserFreeBets.UserForNoBets  
            FROM
                tbl_CreateFreeBet, tbl_UserFreeBets 
            WHERE
                tbl_CreateFreeBet.MatchID = tbl_UserFreeBets.MatchID 
                AND tbl_CreateFreeBet.TournamentID = tbl_UserFreeBets.MatchID 
                AND tbl_CreateFreeBet.FreeBetID = tbl_UserFreeBets.FreebetID 
                AND tbl_UserFreeBets.FreebetID = @FreeBetId
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @strResp = 'Free bet already exist'

        ROLLBACK TRAN @TransactionNewFreeBet
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @strResp = 'MAX 50 user bets can be created for a match'
    ROLLBACK TRAN @TransactionNewFreeBet
END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @strResp = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    ROLLBACK transaction sp_CreateNewFreeBet
END CATCH
END
```

Please let me know what should i be doing to fix this issue.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged